# ORDER BY and DISTINCT in same select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, distinct

I have calculated a daily figure that brings together all figures entered across each name so i have duplicate rows under each name. I want the results to show only one result per user so i figured that it was best to use distinct. However, i also need to display the results by descending figure. Is this possible to do in the same statement?

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
    D.DATE, 
    COALESCE( M.[Team ADJ],D.[Team ADJ], M.[Name]) AS 'Sales Person',
    COALESCE( D.[Team], M.[Team]) AS 'Sales Team',
    isnull(D.[Daily Figure],0) AS [Daily Figure],

    FROM  
    [Daily] D
    FULL OUTER JOIN
    [Month] M ON D.[Name] = F.[Name]
    ORDER BY [Daily Figure] DESC
```

Current results

```
 Date       Sales Person    Sales Team     Daily Figure    Month 
 2017-09-19     FRED         SAM               20           285
 2017-09-19     FRED         SAM               20           285
 2017-09-19     FRED         SAM               20           285
 2017-09-19     TOM          BEN               140          118
 2017-09-19     TOM          BEN               140          118
```

ERROR:'ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.' Even though i have included it in the select list

Comment: Why is there a `Date` column in your results when there isn't one in your `SELECT`? Otherwise your query should work fine.

Comment: If you join by name only, you'd get for, say, 3 `Month` records and 90 `Daily` records a result of 270 rows for that one name only. Is this intended? Please think about what you want to see in your results. One record per name and month? One record per name and day? One record per name? What are the columns `Date`, `Daily Figure`, and `Month` supposed to contain?

Comment: "I want `DISTINCT` but..." is usually a clue that you should be looking a) at why you're getting duplicate results in the first place and/or b) at whether you actually need `GROUP BY` and aggregates instead. At the moment, it's unclear to me whether this is more of an (a) or (b) situation.

Comment: When doing SELECT DISTINCT you can only ORDER BY select list items.

Comment: The single quote is for sting literals by the way. Don't use them for alias names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to resolve this issue is to order by the column number position. E.G. If the column is in the 4th position 'order by 4'

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
COALESCE( M.[Team ADJ],D.[Team ADJ], M.[Name]) AS 'Sales Person',
COALESCE( D.[Team], M.[Team]) AS 'Sales Team',
isnull(D.[Daily Figure],0),

FROM  
[Daily] D
FULL OUTER JOIN
[Month] M ON D.[Name] = F.[Name]
ORDER BY 4 DESC
```

Comment: I advise against ordering by the column ordinal in saved production code.  It can introduce a point of failure when someone modifies the code later.  However, I use them all the time in run-once queries.

Answer (score 1):

In the `order by` section, you can reference the column by its alias, e.g.:

```
select distinct 
    [Date]
  , coalesce( M.[Team adj],D.[Team adj], M.[Name]) as [Sales Person]
  , coalesce( D.[Team], M.[Team]) as [Sales Team]
  , isnull(D.[Daily Figure],0) as [Daily Figure]
  , [Month]
from  [Daily] D
  full outer join [Month] M 
    on D.[Name] = F.[Name]
order by [Daily Figure] desc
```

---

Without the source tables to build the query, here is a demo using your sample above:

```
select distinct
    t.Date, 
    [Sales Person],
    [Sales Team],
    isnull(t.[Daily Figure],0) AS [Daily Figure]
from t
order by [Daily Figure] desc
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/PVPHSR35614

returns:

```
+------------+--------------+------------+--------------+
|    Date    | Sales Person | Sales Team | Daily Figure |
+------------+--------------+------------+--------------+
| 2017-09-19 | tom          | ben        |          140 |
| 2017-09-19 | fred         | sam        |           20 |
+------------+--------------+------------+--------------+
```

Comment: error 'ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.' I have included it in the select list

Answer (score 0):

The sample query did not generate the current results you've posted.

In a Distinct Order By, the order column must be part of the result set.  In your sample query, there is not a column named Daily Figure.  If Daily Figure was used without an expression, the Order By would work fine.  However, once you wrap it in an expression, it is no longer named Daily Figure.

The simplest fix is to alias the column.

```
, isnull(D.[Daily Figure],0) as [Daily Figure]
```

*** Update ***

Here is a snippet you can run on any SQL Server showing Distinct Order By in action.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
            t.type_desc,
            CAST(t.create_date AS DATE) AS Created
  FROM      sys.tables AS t
  ORDER BY  Created
;
```

Comment: i have tried this with an alias but it doesnt work in sql server

Comment: Update the query statement you posted in your question.  There is something we are missing.   I have used Distinct Order By many times.  Its rules are pretty straightforward.

Comment: That is the code lol. I have used with order 3 and it works fine

Comment: SQL Server definitely allows Distinct Order By with an alias.  I've just posted a code snippet showing it.

Comment: It just wasnt allowing to order by on an alias in my code. Could it be to do with COALESCE?

Comment: That is why I asked you to repost your code.  The query you posted does not match the results you posted or your description of what you've tried.